# Windows build source fails silently due to use of {} for initialization rather than () - why?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw-w64

It has taken me most of the day but I have managed to isolate a single line of code which causes my program to silently fail during runtime.

The difference is this:

```
: data(std::move(value)) // this works

: data{std::move(value)} // this causes a silent runtime failure
```

I have tested my source code using mingw 7, which is what I had installed already. (Downloaded from mingw's site.) And now I have tested with mingw64 12.2.0. (Which I just downloaded.)

The question is what is going on here?

Here's my source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


template<typename T>
void draw(const T& t, std::ostream& os, std::size_t position)
{
    os << std::string(position, ' ') << t << std::endl;
}


class Object
{
public:

    template<typename T>
    Object(T value)
        : p_data(new Model<T>(std::move(value)))
    {

    }

    Object(const Object& object)
        : p_data(object.p_data->copy())
    {

    }

    Object(Object&& other) noexcept = default;

    Object& operator=(const Object& object)
    {
        Object tmp(object);
        *this = std::move(tmp);
        return *this;
    }

    Object& operator=(Object&& object) noexcept = default;

    friend void draw(const Object& object, std::ostream& os, std::size_t position)
    {
        object.p_data->draw_internal(os, position);
    }

private:

    struct Concept
    {
        virtual ~Concept() = default;
        virtual Concept* copy() const = 0;
        virtual void draw_internal(std::ostream&, std::size_t) const = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Model : Concept
    {
        Model(T value)
            : data(std::move(value))       // <<<< this works
            //: data{std::move(value)}     // <<<< this causes a problem - why?
        { }

        Concept* copy() const override
        {
            return new Model(*this);
        }

        void draw_internal(std::ostream& os, std::size_t position) const override
        {
            draw(data, os, position);
        }

        T data;
    };
    
    std::unique_ptr<Concept> p_data;
};


using Document = std::vector<Object>;

void draw(const Document& document, std::ostream& os, std::size_t position)
{
    os << std::string(position, ' ') << "<document>" << std::endl;
    for(const auto & item : document)
    {
        draw(item, os, position + 4);
    }
    os << std::string(position, ' ') << "</document>" << std::endl;
}
```

```
#include "typeerased_original.h"


int main()
{
    std::cout << "start of main" << std::endl;

    Document document;

    document.push_back(0);
    document.push_back(std::string("Hello World"));
    std::cout << "push back document" << std::endl;
    document.push_back(document);
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl; // fails before this line is emitted

    std::cout << "Drawing now!" << std::endl;
    draw(document, std::cout, 0);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled this using C++ Standard set to 17 (CMake). Windows 10. I'm not really a windows guy so I don't know if I can give more detail than this.

AFAIK `{}` should be equivalent to `()` in this context. (Member initization list vs class style initialization - maybe there is a different naming convention for these two things, if so I may not be aware of it.)

Is this a compiler bug? If so it seems to have existed for a long time. (5 major versions of GCC?)

Comment: Without looking it up, my first thought is "zero initialization difference"..?

Comment: It causes a stack overflow for whatever reason. https://godbolt.org/z/T94zjjeob

Comment: You are trying to insert the document into itself - is that intentional? I could see some weird recursion shenanigans happening there as copying the object requires copying itself.

Comment: To address the questions about infinite recursion: The answer is no, due to value symantics. You can find a video about this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIhUE5uUFOA&t=825s

And you can find the source code here: https://gist.github.com/martinmoene/cd3286daa799acc55cc0

Comment: I think `return new Model(*this);` in `copy` is an error. I think it should be `new Model(*p_data);`. Otherwise it seems like you would be creating a Model of a Model.

Comment: In other words, how it is supposed to work (and does work when fixing the bug by using `()` instead of `{}`) is like this: This wrapper class is a type erasure object. It can contain anything. Including a vector of itself. However, objects are passed to it for initialization by value. This means copies are made, and there are no circular references anywhere. Or at least there isn't supposed to be.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux There is no `p_data` there but there is a `data`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I tested this change, using `new Model(data)` and the result is the same?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Yes, I meant `data`. Shouldn't that be `new Model(*data)`? Otherwise you are making a model for a pointer. Consider using `new Model<T>(...)` to make sure you aren't accidentally creating the wrong thing. I'm not assuming this is the cause of the problem, but it does seem to be a mistake.

Comment: In the case of pushing back a vector `data{std::move(value)}` would use the `std::initializer_list` constructor if it compatible, and not the move constructor. For `std::vector` the expression `v(3,4)` and `v{3,4}` are very different. The first contains `{4,4,4}` and the other `{3,4}`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The `std::intializer_list` constructor is only used when it is passed a list of elements.  Yes, list initialization is happening, but it is not using the `std::initializer_list` constructor.

Comment: You should mark the constructor `template<typename T> Object(T)` as `explicit` else it is a good source of ambiguity in the code.

Comment: @NathanOliver At first I couldn't actually see how the initializer list came into play, but because `std::vector<Object>` is implicitly convertible to `Object` due to `Object::Object<T>(T value)` the initializer list does get used with `{}`.

Answer (score 3):

> AFAIK {} should be equivalent to () in this context. (Member
> initization list vs class style initialization - maybe there is a
> different naming convention for these two things, if so I may not be
> aware of it.)

You are right for all arguments but `std::vector<Object>`.

`std::vector<Object>(std::move(value))` (where `value` is `std::vector<Object>` itself) resolves into a move-constructor:

```
std::vector( std::vector&& );
```

However the use of braced syntax `{}` ends up with `std::initializer_list` constructor:

```
std::vector( std::initializer_list<T>, const Allocator& );
```

So it means that for braced-init-list initialisation you try to make a vector of vectors of the same type (indirectly, through `Object` constructor), and it makes an infinite template argument recursion to happen, which in turn causes the error.

##### EDIT

The most confusing part here is that `Object` is not apparent about being convertible to `std::vector<Object>` until instantiation of the constructor `template<typename T> Object(T value)` comes into play. When you  call `document.push_back(document);` the instantiation of the template turns into `Object(std::vector<Object> value)`, so in this context `std:: initializer_list<std::vector<Object>>` becomes (implicitly) convertible to `std::initializer_list<Object>` and that makes it possible for instance of `std::vector<Object>` to be initialised with braced initialisation with elements of the same type as the vector itself. (`std::vector<Object>` gets converted to `Object` via constructor `Object(std::vector<Object>)` and `std::vector(std::initializer_list<T>)` becomes a viable overload, which always precede any other constructors when using the braced initialisation).

As a result you don't copy content of the `std::vector<Object>` argument via move-constructor, but pass it as an element. And instead has a vector, which template type is infinitely looped through the instantiation of the `Object` constructor (`Object` with `std::unique_ptr` of `Concept` with `std::vector` of `Object` with `std::unique_ptr` of `Concept` with `std::vector` of `Object` and so on..)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `T` is compatible as far as i can see - `Object(T value)` is not explicit constructor and it takes `std::vector<Object>`, so in `std::initializer_list<Object>` is convertible to `std::initializer_list<std::vector<Object>>`

Comment: You are right, it does occur here. The `std::vector<Object>` being initialized by a list of `std::vector<Object>` is implicitly converting the intializer to a `Object`. This then causes the creation of more `Model<std::vector<Object>>` creating an infinite loop.